# Load Javascript functions on window load dynamically

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to load the functions from separate Javascript files dynamically when a window loads, by setting an array and loader function?

Comment: maybe take a look at [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply add `<script>` elements to the DOM dynamically.

```
<script>
var scripts = [ 'a.js', 'b.js', ... ];
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i) {
  document.write('<script src="' + scripts[i] + '"></' + 'script>');
}
</script>
```

Note that you can only do this before the `DOMContentReady` event is fired.

BTW event Google Closure Library uses this technique. And as a sidenote, you probably want to concatenate the scripts into a single file so that you save yourself (and your users) HTTP requests and get faster page loads.

What's cool about this is that the scripts are downloaded and evaluated right after the closing `</script>` tag so you don't have to wait for anything else before you can use them:

```
<!-- Let's pretend that a.js defines a function A() -->
<script>document.write('<script src="a.js"></' + 'script>');</script>
<script>
var a = new A();
</script>
```

Comment: You can add script tags anytime, not just before `DOMContentReady`. You meant to say you can't use `document.write` after `DOMContentReady`. Just use DOM manipulation to add it.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. By "this", I meant `document.write`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I may as well make this an answer rather than just a comment, [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) has exactly the functionality you're looking for, specifically look at [this](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) docs page to see it's use in-browser.